# Create python development environment (virtualenv) using setup.py

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, setup.py

I am working on a `python` project.

I have already created my `setup.py` file.

Is there a way to make use of `setup.py` file `install_requires` section so as to create my virtualenv, or do I have to explicitly create a `requirements.txt` file and proceed with

- `virtualenv -p python3 venv`
- `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setup.py` installs the package in whichever environment is active. If you want to install it in a virtualenv, then you need to activate it first. Otherwise it will install  globally.

You can continue using `requirements.txt` but let `setup.py` handle the installation. You can then read the file and set the list of dependencies for `install_requires` section.

```py
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.readlines()

setup(
    name='myawesomepackage',
    version='0.1',
    packages=find_packages(),
    url='https://example.com',
    author='abdusco',
    description='',
    install_requires=requirements,
    entry_points=dict(console_scripts=[
        'myawesomeapp=app:main'
    ])
)
```

Here's `requirements.txt`

```
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
idna==2.8
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.3
```