# Create virtual environment from setup.cfg

Tags: python, virtualenv, setuptools, python-packaging, python-poetry

I have a Python project, which uses a SDK (*beam*), which in turn enforces *setuptools*.

Now for my dev environment, I am currently duplicating the library requirements of `setup.cfg` in `poetry`. This way I can then build a custom env/shell easily.

I do wonder though, whether it is possible to use the `install_requires` from `setup.cfg` to setup a virtual env.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. -- If you already have a virtual environment, then `path/to/venv/bin/python -m pip install .` should install your project and its dependencies. -- Why are you using poetry here?

Comment: I mostly try to get an integrated dev setup. So for me this is a means getting Beam + Setuptools and Visual Studio Code integrated/automated as much as possible. Sadly it is absolutely not clear to me how all these different Python tools integrate with each other. So poetry does creation of the venv + manages installing deps inside + is integrated into VSC.

Comment: Answering your original question - no, this is not possible. Creating a new virtual environment will create a new python executable, and the process currently running the installation code is spawned by another python executable.

Comment: If you need the info about the virtual env `poetry` uses - `poetry env info`. If you want to integrate `poetry` in VSCode project config, this is a completely different question.

Comment: Never mind, found another SO thread that answers this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57089252/create-python-development-environment-virtualenv-using-setup-py